# Track active number of plugin installations

Tags: wordpress

I have made a simple WordPress Plugin and I want to keep track of how many and which websites have currently installed my plugin. I am not going to list my plugin on wordpress.org because I am only testing it for my school project.

Are there any solutions available to achieve my task? or any help... Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're not publishing your plugin on wordpress.org, then you'll need to do the tracking yourself to get statistics (as in, you'll need to store and process that data somehow completely on your own). While doing so, you'll also need to be explicit about it so site owners are aware that you're collecting data.

Comment: I am developing it totally to test on my website only. Can you please suggest me how could I call trackback? In my understanding, I think I would have to make an API to another server and pass some sort of `Installation ID` to server from plugin and keep log of it at server. Am I right?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)